# Where are software licenses kept for software bundled with a new MacBook?

Tags: macos, license, logic

I just got a new MacBook Air and when I ordered it online I asked for Logic Pro.  The laptop came with the software, but I don't see a license or anything that ties it to me.  If I need to reinstall the OS on this laptop, or move to a new one, how can I take Logic with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The license will be tied to the Apple ID you used when you purchased the Mac.

Check it in the App Store, under Purchases. Apple doesn't directly tie a purchase to a person, but to an Apple ID. They don't have separate license files or authorisation codes etc.

Comment: So, can you just copy the software from one machine to another, even one with a different Apple ID?

Comment: @lhf Sure, but it's not going to work unless you own it.